# Spark doesn't see Hive tables depending on how you run it

Tags: python, database, apache-spark, hive, spark-submit

The problem is that depending on how you run Spark you can see or not Hive databases. I do three next actions:

1. Using Hive

---

```
hive> show databases;

OK
default
mydb
sparkdb
Time taken: 0.041 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

2. Using pyspark3 shell

---

```
Using Python version 3.6.9 (default, Feb 28 2023 09:55:20)
Spark context Web UI available at http://training.us-west4-b.c.ace-sight-379210.internal:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = yarn, app id = application_1678451025755_0002).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.

>>> spark.sql(""" show databases; """)

23/03/10 12:24:55 WARN HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.stats.jdbc.timeout does not exist
23/03/10 12:24:55 WARN HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.stats.retries.wait does not exist
+---------+
|namespace|
+---------+
|  default|
|     mydb|
|  sparkdb|
+---------+
```

3. Using pyspark script, **spark3-submit --master=yarn script.py**

---

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("yarn").appName("Test").getOrCreate()

print(spark.sql(""" show databases """))
```

output is

```
+---------+
|namespace|
+---------+
|  default|
+---------+
```

Can anyone explain what's wrong with the 3rd method? It doesn't show all tables. The file **hive-site.xml** is copied to spark/conf folder and the 2nd method works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly tell Spark to connect to Hive. This is done by [`enableHiveSupport`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession$$Builder.html#enableHiveSupport():org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.Builder) method on SparkSession Builder.

So it's enough to initialize it using:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder
          .master("yarn").appName("Test")
          .enableHiveSupport()
          .getOrCreate()
```